# Trying to check a valid email using Lex, getting "Undefined definition" error instead

Tags: lex

I'm trying to create a simple program using Lex that checks if a given email address is valid or not. This is how I'm actually trying to achieve this:

**Declarations section**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int correct = 0;
string email;
void write_data(string email, int correct);

/* Alias section */
name      [a-zA-Z]
special    [-_%+-]
digit      [0-9]
domain     [a-z]\.[a-z]{2,5}
email      {name}+({digit} | {special})*@{domain}{1}
%}
```

**Rules section**

```
%%
{email}    {correct = 1;}
%%
```

**Programs section**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc == 2){
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        email = yyin.getline();

        if(yyin == NULL){
            printf("Couldn't open %s file\n", argv[1]);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    else{
        yyin = stdin;
        email = yytext;
    }

    correct = 0;
    yylex();
    write_data(email, correct);

    return 0;
}

void write_data(string email, int correct)
{
    if(correct == 1)
        printf("Email %s is correct\n", correo);

    else   
        printf("Email %s is not correct\n", correo);
}
```

I'm trying to invoke the Lex tool using

```
lex template.l
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> template.h:40: undefined definition {email}

I've been trying for a while already but I couldn't even run Lex on it so I don't know what could be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out for anyone interested. You MUST place the aliases out of the first *%{%}* section. The result of the Declaration section is as follows:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int correct = 0;
string email;
void write_data(string email, int correct);
%}

/* Alias section */
name      [a-zA-Z]
special    [-_%+-]
digit      [0-9]
domain     [a-z]\.[a-z]{2,5}
email      {name}+({digit} | {special})*@{domain}{1}
```

Comment: You also cannot use unescaped whitespace in a pattern so your `email` pattern is incorrect.